# Top tab bar without swipable activity in react native

Tags: tabs, react-native, react-native-tab-view

I am looking for top tab bar not bottom without swipable activity i.e tabs should not scroll horizontally, we should go on other tabs only by clicking on it but not by side scrolling the tabs. Right now I am using Tabs from Native Base.I searched for How should I disable that swipe activity? but yet I cant not found anything about it. I also searched for such tabview but mostly i got the tabs with swipe activity.

So, Is any way to disable it or I am searching the wrong.

If any other top tab bar is available like then please suggest me that i can use it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can check this module out https://github.com/skv-headless/react-native-scrollable-tab-view. I have used it in my projects, this is a good repository. You can disable the horizontal scroll on tabs by applying a **locked** prop as true.

If you still face any issue then do let me know.

Comment: ohhk I will implement it first.